# Asking lines where one Attribute i included two times

Tags: mysql

does anybody know how do get the lines where SCId appears two times with the same Number?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images for sample data instead include sample data in textual format or better to use any online tool, Also include your complete table definitions and expected output

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to filter off non matching records by joining to a subquery which finds all matching `SCId` values appearing twice in your table.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SCId
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY SCId
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) t2
    ON t1.SCId = t2.SCId;
```